# Optical switch and packet generation

Tags: optics

I am building a testbed in the lab which at its core has an optical switch. The input and output from this switch are MTP ports. I am looking for the simplest/cheapest way to test that the optical switch works by sending some bits on a fiber through the MTP port and back out.

Comment: Removed off-topic request for product/resource recommendation.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, the easiest way to test that switch is to connect two NICs with appropriate transceivers (or one with an optical loopback). MTP/MPO are for multi-fiber connections like with short-wavelength QSFP+ (40GBASE-R), but you could likely use MPO/LC adapter cabling and test with simpler SFP/SFP+ gear.

Just make sure that your transceivers match the optics - single-mode fiber (9 μm core) are used with long-wavelength *L* transceivers (1000BASE-LX, 10GBASE-LR, 40GBASE-LR4, ...), and multi-mode fiber (50 μm core) are used with short-wavelength *S* transceivers (1000BASE-SX, 10GBASE-SR, 40GBASE-SR4, ...). Note that most multi-lane, single-mode *L* transceivers use wavelength-division multiplex (WDM) with a single fiber pair, no MPO.

Or you simply shine a light through the switch. If you use a laser make sure you watch your eyes.